# How to translate AM and PM in PHP date

Tags: php, date, arabic

I have a context in a forum settings that use date function to handle datetime string. This context accept the format string of the date function. However, the forum in the Arabic language and I want to translate the string of `am` and `pm` to another equivalent in an Arabic string such as `ص` and `م` respectively. I tried the following code to make the external (the context) date() to replace:

```
echo date("addslashes(date('D d M Y g:i'),'A..Z')".str_ireplace(array('pm','am'), array('م','ص'),date(' a')));
```

I used `addslashes` in hope to escape the output of the first inner date. However the output is something like that:

```
pm202005Sundaypm0509UTC05(20pm30UTC('Sun 20 Apr 2014 9:03'),'PM..0') م
```

It is just scceeded in replacing `am` and `pm` but the whole date string is missy as you see. [This is a live demo](http://ideone.com/V9mDKe) of the code. I need to know does it possible to get what I need, assuming that any code will be done inside a predefined `date()`?

Comment: Wouldn't str_ireplace(..., ..., date(...)) work?

Comment: No, I have not the option to use anything outside `date()` function.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean now.  So you are inserting code into a date().  Is the date() completely empty?  This is going to be a dirty solution and I'm surprised the forum allows you to insert code into it.

Comment: @Devon It is just for administrators. Indeed, to do it I have to manually insert it into the configuration database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator inside the date to set a conditional format.

```
date($format = (date(G) > 11) ? 'h:i \ص' : 'h:i \م');
```

or for am/pm

```
date($format = (date(G) > 11) ? 'h:i \p\m' : 'h:i \a\m');
```

You can set the format different than h:i but this will show `05:40 pm` for 17:40 or `05:40 am` for 05:40.  It looks for date(G) which is the hours in 0-23 format.  If date(G) is greater than 11, it uses the first format, else uses the second format.

Here is a fork of your code http://ideone.com/BobelH

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach. It uses `strtotime` and `str_replace` as follows:

```
<?php
$dtFormat = "Y-m-d H:i:s"; //MySQL Datetime format
$curDT = date($dtFormat);
$curTime = strtotime($curDT);
$nowFormat = "Y-m-d h:i:s ";
$arrEn = array('am', 'pm');
$arrAr = array('ص', 'م');
echo date($nowFormat).str_replace($arrEn, $arrAr,date("a", $curTime));
```

A working demo: http://ideone.com/xfECCD